# Panel directly proportional with form

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to create an application in which the panel width is directly proportional with the form width. I calculated and the panel width is 25/33 of the form width. Here's what I've tried:

```
    Timer timer1 = new Timer();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        timer1.Interval = 1;
        timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(ResizePanel);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void ResizePanel(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Panel1.Width = 25 / 33 * Form1.Width;
    }
```

If one of you guys could help me I would be very happy. And one more thing, please do not send me links to other dynamic libraries because I don't want to depend on any DLL. Thank you very much again.

Comment: Get rid of the timer.  Just set the Anchor properties of the panel to all sides.

Comment: @LarsTech Thanks, I guess I complicated stuff really much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also always nest your `Panel` inside a `TableLayoutPanel` and set its column width to be a percentage - that will automatically resize with the form.